# Bootstrap form fields not clearing after submit

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a Bootstrap 3 form on my website. The form sends messages fine, however when the user submits the form the fields aren't clearing afterwards - how do I fix this?

This is the 'contact.php' code below.

Link to the 'contact_me.js' https://jsfiddle.net/wookie/6uag6goe/

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="contact.php">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errEmail</p>";?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="service" class="control-label">Service</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="service" name="service">
        <option>Please select a service:</option>
        <option>service1</option>
        <option>service2</option>
        <option>service3</option>
        <option>service4</option>
        <option>service5</option>
        <option>service6</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="message" class="control-label">Message</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message">
        <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[ 'message']);?>
    </textarea>
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errMessage</p>";?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="human" class="control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errHuman</p>";?>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <?php echo $result; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are echoing out the posted data. You only want to do that when there is an error in the posted data.

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']); ?>">
```

However you are doing your server side error detection you need to only do the echo above if there is an error. Say you store a $isError variable then you would change this to:-

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" value="<?php echo $isError ?htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']) : ""; ?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
$('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
```

to

```
$('#contactForm')[0].reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

Let your form has an id **contactForm** then:

```
$('#contactForm').on('submit', function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
         this.reset();
    });
});
```